# what does this bat file do?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, malware

I found a file with the following content that was on the flash:

[image: preview of content]

[File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10j6wVRFn74IMLBD9-Zng03FwMDn7ykDo)

1. What coding does it use?
2. How to decode it?

Comment: No-one is going to click through to a random google drive link. Post it as plaintext somewhere 'safe' like here, or if it's too big, pastebin.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Well, I'm certainly not clicking on a _random pastebin link_ and I'm surprised that's considered less malicious than a file stored on Gdrive. I have already _lost count_ of pastebin sites which tried to push driveby malware to anyone who didn't have an adblocker.

Comment: @grawity - then I guess no-one is going to look at it...

Comment: I took the risk, checked your links and posted the image as `.png` form imgur. Our interface is somewhat integrated with imgur. If you took advantage of this instead of linking to Google Drive, users would at least see the image.

Comment: Where did you get this? And what is the full name of this bat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like some variant of a string encoded in
[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

In this case it seems to be an attempt at
[Obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29)
of the contents.

Seeing that the obfuscated part is a PowerShell command,
my best advice is :
**Don't touch this file and don't execute it**.
There is a chance that it will try to infect your computer.

Comment: How to understand what is written?

Comment: You may find a Base64 converters by googling for "Base64 online", where you may copy-paste this code in the website and convert it to text. However, it's possible that this is a non-standard variant of Base64 that was invented by the originating hacker to prevent you from doing just that.

Comment: Someone told me that TheFatRat may have been used!!! what is it? and how Obfuscation solve?!

Comment: I don't know what the obfuscated text means, but highly unlikely that this has anything to do with music. Promising free music is a favorite method of hackers to infect computers.

Answer (score -2):

Bat or batch file is used for automation.
Like parting a disk or anything you do again and again in thr comand prompt. The language it uses is the same commands used inside command prompt. Like DIR, ipconfig.. Etc.  Just write a single command in single line and save as .bat and run it.

Comment: You answered the generic question "what does a bat file do?" from the unfortunate title. The real issue from the question body is "what does *this* bat file do?" Your answer doesn't really answer the question. To do this one should download and analyze the file; but one shouldn't, it may be malicious. So I'm not saying you should answer the specific question right away; I'm saying you shouldn't answer the generic one which is not the real issue. We're waiting for the OP to post the code in a safe form.